# Ignited Datatables, Codeigniter paging/search issue

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatables, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to get [IgnitedDatatables](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables) up and running in a test situation. I am able to populate all the rows with my data, however:

1. The paging system doesn't work. Shows 8 pages but all (72) items are on 1 page. It seems as though `length` isn't being respected despite me seeing a length of 10 in the post data. If I click, for example, page 2 I can see an ajax call being made but it returns the same information that was loaded on page load.
2. The search function doesn't do anything. If I type something in it returns the same information that was loaded on page load.

No console errors. I am using DataTables 1.10.15, responsive version for bootstrap.

I'm usually pretty good with debugging, but I am dealing with a third-party library with [*limited* documentation](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/wiki).

Controller:

```
class Test extends MY_Backend {

    public function index() {

        $this->tpl->head();
        $this->tpl->body();
        $this->load->view('test');
        $this->tpl->footer();
    }

    public function ajax() {

        $this->load->library('datatables');

        $this->datatables
                ->select('id, project_name, created, last_modified')
                ->unset_column('id')
                ->from('projects')
                ->add_column('actions', 'Hello World!');

        $result = $this->datatables->generate('json', '');

        echo $result;
    }

}
```

View/JS (JS + JQUERY loaded in header):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "pageLength": 10,
            "ajax": "/neou_cms/test/ajax",
            "aoColumns": [
                {"mData": "project_name"},
                {"mData": "created"},
                {"mData": "last_modified"},
                {"mData": "actions"}
            ],
        });
    });
</script>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Project Name</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Modified</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to be maintained/updated a lot. Its requirements are: 
jQuery 1.5+, DataTables 1.10+, CodeIgniter "Reactor" (which is CI 1.7, if I remember well), so it looks like you'll need to look into the source code to get it running for CI 3.x, as it is based on old/deprecated libraries

Comment: Seems to be the case. Weird because I thought I'd give it a try as I saw a question roll by regarding it. Seems as though the new methodology is get instead of post so none of the vars are getting populated.

Comment: I didn't look into the source, but originally it was written by Phil Sturgean, who was actually one of the 6 CI developers of the "reactor" branch back in 2009/10. So I'm sure it worked fine back then. Now it's 100 years later: 2018

Comment: I think it was updated since then about a few years ago. Nevertheless it seems to work fine after a simple js modification to switch get to post. I will probably see if callbacks for columns are supported, if not I will update the code and try to push something on git.

Comment: great you found the solution, hope it will help the "question roll by" user and others.

Answer (score 1):

I guess somewhere between 1.10 and 1.10.15 datatables started using `$_GET` as a default. Using the example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html) I was able to change the ajax type to `POST` and everything is working as expected.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "pageLength": 10,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/neou_cms/test/ajax",
                "type": "POST"
            },
            "columns": [
                {"data": "project_name"},
                {"data": "created"},
                {"data": "last_modified"},
                {"data": "actions", "orderable": false, "searchable": false}
            ],

        });
    });
</script>
```